# Problem in flashing and running STM32 bluepill in linux environment

Tags: c, linux, embedded, stm32, embedded-linux

I am new to STM32 programming. I have bluepill hardware with me. My goal is to flash a simple program (such as blink an led in bluepill) using opensource tools and ubuntu OS.
I am currently following the book "Beginning STM32 developing with freeRTOS libopencm3 and GCC" for the same.
As per the book
I have downloaded the book software using git clone https://github.com/ve3wwg/stm32f103c8t6.git
I have downloaded the libopencm3 in stm32f103c8t6 folder using git clone https://github.com/libopencm3/libopencm3.git
I have downloaded freertos (version FreeRTOSv10.2.1.zip) from sourceforge and unzip in location /stm32f103c8t62/rtos/
I have made required changes in /stm32f103c8t6/rtos/Project.mk file "FREERTOS        ?= FreeRTOSv10.2.1"
I have installed ARM cross compiler using sudo apt install gcc-arm-none-eabi
I have build the software using following command "$ cd ~/stm32f103c8t6" and "$ make"
Then i have installed st-flash tool

There is pre written code named as miniblink.c in miniblink folder
code is as follows:

```
#include <libopencm3/stm32/rcc.h>
#include <libopencm3/stm32/gpio.h>

static void
gpio_setup(void) {

    /* Enable GPIOC clock. */
    rcc_periph_clock_enable(RCC_GPIOC);

    /* Set GPIO8 (in GPIO port C) to 'output push-pull'. */
    gpio_set_mode(GPIOC,GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_2_MHZ,
              GPIO_CNF_OUTPUT_PUSHPULL,GPIO13);
}

int
main(void) {
    int i;

    gpio_setup();

    for (;;) {
        gpio_clear(GPIOC,GPIO13);   /* LED on */
        for (i = 0; i < 1500000; i++)   /* Wait a bit. */
            __asm__("nop");

        gpio_set(GPIOC,GPIO13);     /* LED off */
        for (i = 0; i < 500000; i++)    /* Wait a bit. */
            __asm__("nop");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I have connected my bluepill using st-link v2 to my computer.

I have used following commands in terminal from miniblink folder "$ make clobber" followed by "$ make" followed by "$ make flash" as given in textbook.

it shows following output in terminal:

```
 /usr/bin/st-flash  write miniblink.bin 0x8000000
st-flash 1.6.0
2022-04-07T21:44:50 INFO common.c: Loading device parameters....
2022-04-07T21:44:50 INFO common.c: Device connected is: F1 Low-density device, id 0x10006412
2022-04-07T21:44:50 INFO common.c: SRAM size: 0x2800 bytes (10 KiB), Flash: 0x8000 bytes (32 KiB) in pages of 1024 bytes
2022-04-07T21:44:50 INFO common.c: Attempting to write 688 (0x2b0) bytes to stm32 address: 134217728 (0x8000000)
Flash page at addr: 0x08000000 erased
2022-04-07T21:44:50 INFO common.c: Finished erasing 1 pages of 1024 (0x400) bytes
2022-04-07T21:44:50 INFO common.c: Starting Flash write for VL/F0/F3/F1_XL core id
2022-04-07T21:44:50 INFO flash_loader.c: Successfully loaded flash loader in sram
  1/1 pages written
2022-04-07T21:44:50 INFO common.c: Starting verification of write complete
2022-04-07T21:44:50 INFO common.c: Flash written and verified! jolly good!
```

Also the book doesn't mention about whether BOOT0 is HIGH or LOW during flashing.

I tried flashing bluepill with both settings BOOT0 HIGH and BOOT0 LOW

But in either case I don't see PC13 green LED blink in the bluepill after flashing.

Where am I going wrong. How to check whether the code is getting flashed to the bluepill?
What should I do to get the green led blink in the bluepill?

Answer (score -1):

You are programming with JTAG or SWD.  The state of BOOT0 does not matter while you are programming.

The level of BOOT0 only matters during the rising edge of nRST (for example after you have finished programming).  If BOOT0 is high and BOOT1 is low the embedded serial bootloader will run instead of your program, which is probably not what you want.  See [AN2606](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/cd00167594-stm32-microcontroller-system-memory-boot-mode-stmicroelectronics.pdf) for details.